# Equivalent for libSgm's Dial

Tags: linux, x11, irix

I am porting a complex software from IRIX to Linux Red-Hat.
It now uses the Dial widget from libSgm (see [here](http://techpubs.sgi.com/library/dynaweb_docs/0530/SGI_Developer/books/IndigoMagic_IG/sgi_html/ch04.html#id23968) for example).
I searched quite a while and didn't find any equivalent/replacement for libSgm nor specifically for Dial, that I can use on Linux.

Does anybody know?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The only one I know of that is available is the thumbwheel widget. It's in the open sourced Open Inventor library and can be obtained here: https://github.com/aumuell/open-inventor (original here: http://oss.sgi.com/projects/inventor/)